# Is the current form an entityform form?

Tags: 7, forms

I am using [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module on subscribing certain organic groups forms.
I only need to add some custom submit logic when unsubscribing the form if the subscribe form was created with entityform.

Depending on if the subscribing form was generated by entityform, when unsubscribing I need to do some custom logic to clean up the DB from entity data not covered by entityform.

I am using hook_formID_alter, and this is my $form array:

[image]

The thing is I need to do a database clean up if it was submited with entityform in the first place, even though I understand the unsubscribe form is not a entityform.

Therefore, this doesn't work: `if (isset($form['#entity_type']) && $form['#entity_type'] === 'entityform')`

Can you help me identify programmatically which kind of form is the form?

Comment: Did you already check the module's code? How are they doing it?

Comment: @leymannx I don't know if they needed the if statement or not. I couldn't find it, but I am happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to sum up the existing answers both `hook_form_alter` and `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter` can be used to identify Entityform forms. The output in your question comes from some Organic Group unsubscribe form, identifiable by `$form['#form_id']` which equals `og_ui_confirm_unsubscribe`. A totally different form. You probably have to go to [example.com/eform/submit/MYENTITYFORM](http://example.com/eform/submit/MYENTITYFORM) to fetch some actual form output.

Although I must admit I don't understand what exactly you want to do there, both of the following snippets will work. Place them in your custom module or theme, replace `MYMODULE` with your module's or theme's machine name, flush cache, code on!

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#entity_type']) && $form['#entity_type'] === 'entityform') {
    dpm($form);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_entityform_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
}
```

---

To distinguish if any arbitrary form is placed on a certain URL you can do the following by using just `arg()` or the path alias:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // AFAIK all Entitforms URLs start with /eform.
  // You can simply broaden this request to match
  // more advanced patterns.
  if (arg(0, drupal_get_path_alias()) === 'eform') {
    dpm($form);
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue has never been the function hooks, but when unsubscribing, there is no way to tell if the form was actually submited from entityform in the first place, thats why the if statement doesn't work as isset($form['#entity_type'] is always false and $form['#entity_type'] === 'entityform' is not present in the $form array as you can see in the screenshot I have inserted on the question. I hope its now clear

Comment: @Jorge – This is very important key information that is missing in your question. Please update your question to clarify: You have some unsubscribe form that is placed on Entityform forms (as block? per block visibility settings limited to a certain URL pattern?) and when this form is submitted you want to add some custom submit logic to that form? Is it that?

Comment: I only need to add some custom submit logic when unsubscribing the form if the subscribe form was created with entityform

Comment: @Jorge – OK, and what is it exactly that you need now to finish this task? To know how to add a custom submit function?

Comment: I have updated my question. I know how to add a custom submit function and the hooks are good, when clicking unsubscribe, the remaining task is to find out if the subscribing form was actually created with entityform ( or not ). That is the if statement I have been having struggles with.

Comment: @Jorge – The fog is slowly lifting. Only thing that remains unclear now is: The form in your issue is no Entityorm. It's some unsubscribe form provided by Organic Groups. How exactly does this form got placed on your Entityorm/Entityform's page?

Comment: You are right. The unsubscribing form is no entityform, and has no formal support for Organic Groups but when I subscribed I managed to get entityform working, due to the possibility to add up fields. The URL path settings option to set Submit url to "group/node/1330/subscribe/og_user_node". Because not all my groups have entityform, when I unsubscribe, I will always need to find out in code if the unsubscribing person used a group with entityform or not.

Comment: @Jorge – And is to distinguish via URL pattern no option then? I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to implement a `*_form_alter()` function in a module (which is what I got out of your post), you can implement [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x), which in this case would be `hook_form_node_form_alter()`. If you implement this, it will only be executed if/when you are on a node form, and therefore you will know you are in a node form.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. They're not nodes. They are organic groups confirmation forms created with entityform. Please check the link.

Comment: Looks like you can use hook_form_og_ui_confirm_unsubscribe_alter() then.

Comment: The problem is not the hook but how can I create a if statement checking if the actual form was customized with entityform? Some forms are standard, some are entityform

Answer (score 0):

You can check entity form as

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#entity_type'] == 'entityform') {
    // YOUR CODE HERE.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have updated my question with a screenshot of $form array. There isn't a any clue. I have checked inside all the arrays

Comment: Actually `$form['#entity_type']` this will define what type of form is rendered. But in your case, you are using the custom form. So 'entity_type` will not be present in that.

Comment: You code is good, but your if statements isn't computing :)